# Visual Studio unable to recognise my MFC library for my webcam laser rangefinder code

Tags: c++, visual-studio, mfc

I tried copying the source code from the internet directly and I couldn't build/debug the whole file because of the error found below.

Please Help

```
Error occurred while restoring NuGet packages: System.ArgumentException: The path is not                         of a legal form. at System.IO.Path.NormalizePath(String path, Boolean fullCheck, Int32 maxPathLength,Boolean expandShortPaths)
at System.IO.Path.GetDirectoryName(String path)
at NuGet.VisualStudio.VsUtility.GetNuGetSolutionFolder(Solution solution)
at NuGet.VsEvents.PackageRestorer.UsingOldPackageRestore(Solution solution)
at NuGet.VsEvents.PackageRestorer.BuildEvents_OnBuildBegin(vsBuildScope Scope,   vsBuildAction Action).


1>------ Build started: Project: LaserRange, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>C:\Program Files   (x86)\MSBuild\Microsoft.Cpp\v4.0\V120\Microsoft.CppBuild.targets(369,5): error MSB8031: Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820 for more information.
```

========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========}

Comment: The end of it is telling you the exact problem: "Building an MFC project for a non-Unicode character set is deprecated. You must change the project property to Unicode or download an additional library. See http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/p/?LinkId=286820 for more information."

Comment: Configuration problem.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

right click your solution, go to properties and set the project properties to use Unicode instead.

Comment: how *exactly* is this done?   sounds simple enough but i don't see this option when i right click the solution and goto properties in visual studio 2013

Comment: general->project default->character set. However, I think the working solution is install add-on as mentioned by @thoma, especially when you are using code from existing projects.

Comment: For VS2013, right click the Project, not the Solution.  The answer here says to right click the Solution... maybe that works in some other versions of VS.

Answer (score 21):

*Question* : Where do I "**change the project property to Unicode**"?

*Answer* :

For C++,

Right Click the project, and select properties,  ( or Alt-Enter )
**Property Pages** should open

Under **Configuration Properties**

**General**

[-]**Project Defaults**

```
  **Character Set** : Use Multi-Byte Character Set
```

- Change to -

```
  **Character Set** : Use Unicode Character Set
```

Pain in the butt to find it.

Answer (score 14):

you need to install MFC MBCS DLL Add-on As mentioned in your error.
See the below link
http://msdn.microsoft.com/library/dn251007.aspx

Comment: This is much more failproof than the marked solution. If you rely on a Multi-Byte dependency it will get ugly as soon as you change your dependency to Unicode. At least when you are leafing the overlapping character space.

Answer (score 1):

I encountered the same issue while building solution in Visual Studio and it got resolved when installed below components:

- MFC for C++
- Common tools for C++
- Windows 8.1 SDK and universal CRT SDK